# SSMS / SQLCMD batch to create all stored procedures within a sub-folder

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssms

I developped the following T-SQL script with a bit of SQLCMD to call separate stored procedure script for their creations. The stored procedures are located in a child `Store Procedure\` folder (I want to keep the space).

They are probably better ways to perform it, but I wan to a unique script (but using files) which creates the database, the tables, the stored procedures and so on.

I detail neither the the database, nor the table scripting.

```
/* Create database (I still have some issues with dropping it (existing connections) */

*/ Create tables with constraints... */

-- Is it possible to declare a relative path (here MY_PARENT_PATH is replaced by "c:\...")
:setvar STORE_PROCEUDRE_PATH "[MY_PARENT_PATH]\Stored Procedures"

-- Calls CRUD stored procedures from separate scripts via SQLCMD - is it possible to batch it with all spXXX_XXXX.sql files included in the sub-folder?
:r $(STORE_PROCEUDRE_PATH)\spFields_Create.sql
:r $(STORE_PROCEUDRE_PATH)\spFields_Read.sql
:r $(STORE_PROCEUDRE_PATH)\spFields_Update.sql
:r $(STORE_PROCEUDRE_PATH)\spFields_Delete.sql

-- Idem for other table, such as Features, Values, etc.
```

Is it possible to loop all files spXXX_XXXX.sql files within the `Store Procedure\` folder and execute the `:r $(STORE_PROCEUDRE_PATH)\spXXX_XXXX.sql` scripts?

I came accross several articles which show example using a `FOR` construct, but I got confused.

Thanks for any insights :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes there is a way ,
SQLCMD is not able to loop through files but you can use Windows Batch Scripting to accomplish that.

here is a good blog about how to do it :
[SQLCMD and Batch File magic](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/sqlcmd-and-batch-file-magic)

so basically you need to make a .bat file ex: CRUDE.bat and edit and paste below code in it and save it ,

```
@@echo off
cd "[MY_PARENT_PATH]\Stored Procedures"

FOR %%A IN (*.SQL) DO ( sqlcmd -S [SERVERNAME] -d [DATABASE] -U [][username -P password] -i "%%A")
```

you need to replace these values with your values :

MY_PARENT_PATH : Your path or Directory where your suborder is.

SERVERNAME : Your Database Server Name.

DATABASE1 : Your Database name.

Username : Your SQL Username.

Password : Your SQL Password.

now you can run the batch file and it does the magic.

also [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver15) you can find out more about SQLCMD utility

Comment: OK, thanks but it is apparently not as straightforward to call T-SQL scripts from other another one. I still need to think about it, because from what I understand SQLCMD is to be normally executed from outside SSMS, right? I'm probably going to write everything in a SQL Server project directly from Visual Studio.

Comment: correct , however if you tell us what is your original problem to solve maybe we can help you better.